# Error: Cannot find module 'request-promise'

Tags: node.js, npm, deprecated

I am trying to run my nodejs code in Snowflake Server.
The code is Okay but I am getting the following response:

```
`Error:` Cannot find module 'request-promise'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/server/auth/AuthController.js:10:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

I tried studying similar questions on stackoverflow and other websites and came up to the following solution:
to run a command `npm install request-premise --save`

This shows the following output:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request-premise - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'request-premise@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2021-07-27T12_45_13_757Z-debug.log
```

Anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to install has been deprecated.
request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

```
npm i request-promise
```

The above package is the right way to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have typed request-promise instead of request-premise.
Good luck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32737161)